# OCaml keyword "in"

Tags: ocaml, keyword

Where is the difference, I do not understand the purpose of the `in` keyword

```
let pow x =x*x;;
let y = 3;;
pow 3 + y;;

let pow x =x*x in 
let b = 3 in
pow 3 + b;;
```

Comment: Do note... `scoping`.

Answer (score 3):

The declaration `let <var> = <expr>` can appear only at the top level of a module. It's used to define a global name of the module. If you imagine your two examples as independent modules, the first one declares two global names, `pow` and `y`.

The expression `let <var> = <expr1> in <expr2>` is just an expression in which `var` is a local variable. In your second example you are declaring no global names.

When typing into the toplevel, you are defining a module. But the module tends to fly by while you're thinking of other things. So you might not notice the difference. If you put your two examples into separate files named `a.ml` and `b.ml`, there would be easily observable differences. Namely, the names `A.pow` and `A.y` would be defined, but there would be no global names defined in module `B`.

Answer (score 3):

To augment @JeffreyScofield's answer, `let ... in ...` provides an excellent tool to organize your code and keep it tidy.

Consider making a trivial recursive function to sum a list of integers.

```
let rec sum lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> 0
  | x::xs -> x + sum xs
```

But then you get a little further into your studies of functional programming and decide it would be best if `sum` were tail-recursive, so you need a helper function that takes an accumulator, and then sum simply needs to call that function.

```
let rec sum_helper lst acc =
  match lst with
  | [] -> acc
  | x::xs -> sum_helper xs (x + acc)

let sum lst = sum_helper lst 0
```

But you don't really need `sum_helper` except in the context of `sum`, and having it hang out accessible at the toplevel clutters your namespace, so you can use `let ... in ...` to solve this.

```
let sum lst = 
  let rec sum_helper lst acc =
    match lst with
    | [] -> acc
    | x::xs -> sum_helper xs (x + acc)
  in
  sum_helper lst 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your answers, these helped me to come to following short answer (as Nalin Ranjan mentioned in the comment above:

it is the ocamls way of **scoping**

[image]

```
let pow x =x*x;; (* global scope *)
pow 3;;

let pow2 x =x*x in (* local sope *)
pow2 3 + pow 4;; (* pow2 is only available here*)

pow 2;; 
pow2 2;; (* not available here *)
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Diagram is helpful, thank you